# react-native run-android android-sdk does not exists

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I am doing the `react-native` [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) on a Windows 10 system.  I was able to do the `react-native init AwesomeProject` command to work and now I need to execute:

```
>react-native run-android
```

But that fails with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory 'C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 0.64 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I think the problem is that I have installed the latest Android SDK and now the path is this: `C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` and NOT `C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Local\Android-sdk`.  If I where on a Unix like OS I would just make a syslink.  But I am using Windows 10.  What can I do? How do you make syslinks in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows it looks at the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. You should be able to just update that, close out the command prompt or powershell and restart it then try again.

Answer (score 0):

**In Android local.properties Inside Change your 
Sdk Location And solve this issue**

1 react-native start --reset-cache

and go to android folder 
cd android
and then clean gradle

2 gradlew clean

and Make Sure Uninstall the Previous app

**[image]**